# PHP Find and Preg_replace a regex in a string

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I want the regex to replace with just tweet id. I tried the below regex but doesn't work.

```
$string = "The meeting, which was also attended by Chief Bisi Akande, held at the Abuja House in London, a tweet from the presidency revealed.

[twt]https://twitter.com/NGRPresident/status/829704039952740352[/twt]

[twt]https://mobile.twitter.com/NGRPresident/status/829713387001114625[/twt]

President Buhari has been away from Nigeria since January when he departed for a 10-day medical vacation.";
$regex = '/\[twt\]\/https?://twitter\.com/(?:\#!/)?(\w+)/status(es)?/(\d+)[\/twt\]/';
$string = preg_replace("$regex", '$3', $string);
echo $string;'
```

i want the result to ouput;

The meeting, which was also attended by Chief Bisi Akande, held at the Abuja House in London, a tweet from the presidency revealed.

829704039952740352

829713387001114625

President Buhari has been away from Nigeria since January when he departed for a 10-day medical vacation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/\[twt\]https?:\/\/(?:\w+\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status(?:es)?\/(\d+)\[\/twt\]/
```

Substitute with

```
$1
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZDY3G/1)